# XSLT Sort of Loops shifted some below nodes up

Tags: xslt

My XSLT logic is not working. Can we check why its not Sorting the S5_Loop is working but it moved L3 and SE sections above S5_Loop. Here is the XSL, I am using, its version 1.0. I can only use version 1.0. This is not right output, it should sort S5_Loop bit keep the remaining fields in same place.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 
<xsl:template match="/ST_Loop">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="S5/S501"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ST_Loop>
    <N1_Loop>
        <N1>
            <N101>CN</N101>
            <N102 GROUP            03</N102>
        </N1>
        <N3>
            <N301></N301>
        </N3>
        <N4>
            <N401>S</N401>
            <N403>-1300</N403>
            <N404>US</N404>
        </N4>
        <G61>
            <G6101>CN</G6101>
            <G6102> </G6102>
            <G6103>TE</G6103>
            <G6104>781-596-0345</G6104>
        </G61>
    </N1_Loop>
    <S5_Loop>
        <S5>
            <S501>1</S501>
            <S502>LD</S502>
        </S5>
        <G62>
            <G6202>200929</G6202>
            <G6204>010000</G6204>
        </G62>
        <N1_Loop>
            <N1>
                <N101>ford</N101>
            </N1>
            <N3>
                <N301>St</N301>
            </N3>
            <N4>
                <N401>ster</N401>
                <N403>-1656</N403>
                <N404>US</N404>
            </N4>
        </N1_Loop>
        <OID_Loop/>
    </S5_Loop>
    <S5_Loop>
        <S5>
            <S501>3</S501>
            <S502>LD</S502>
        </S5>
        <G62/>
        <N1_Loop>
            <N1>
                <N101>LLC</N101>
            </N1>
            <N3>
                <N301>Great Rd</N301>
            </N3>
            <N4>
                <N401>Qiddlesex</N401>
                <N403>-2802</N403>
                <N404>US</N404>
            </N4>
        </N1_Loop>
        <OID_Loop/>
    </S5_Loop>
    <S5_Loop>
        <S5>
            <S501>5</S501>
            <S502>LD</S502>
        </S5>
        <G62/>
        <N1_Loop>
            <N1>
                <N101></N101>
            </N1>
            <N3>
                <N301>St</N301>
            </N3>
            <N4>
                <N401>Rssex</N401>
                <N403>-3308</N403>
                <N404>US</N404>
            </N4>
        </N1_Loop>
        <OID_Loop/>
    </S5_Loop>
    <S5_Loop>
        <S5>
            <S501>2</S501>
            <S502>UL</S502>
        </S5>
        <G62>
            <G6202>2021929</G6202>
            <G6204>040000</G6204>
        </G62>
        <LAD/>
        <N1_Loop>
            <N1>
                <N101>ST</N101>
                <N102></N102>
            </N1>
            <N3>
                <N301>297 Rd</N301>
            </N3>
            <N4>
                <N401>Bedfd</N401>
                <N402>MA</N402>
                <N403>-2802</N403>
                <N404>US</N404>
            </N4>
        </N1_Loop>
    </S5_Loop>
    <S5_Loop>
        <S5>
            <S501>4</S501>
            <S502>UL</S502>
        </S5>
        <G62>
            <G6202>2021029</G6202>
            <G6204>040000</G6204>
        </G62>
        <LAD/>
        <N1_Loop>
            <N1>
                <N101>ST</N101>
                <N102> &amp; , INC.        02</N102>
            </N1>
            <N3>
                <N301>13 Ell St</N301>
            </N3>
            <N4>
                <N401>Beer</N401>
                <N402>MA</N402>
                <N403>-3308</N403>
                <N404>US</N404>
            </N4>
        </N1_Loop>
    </S5_Loop>
    <S5_Loop>
        <S5>
            <S501>6</S501>
            <S502>UL</S502>
        </S5>
        <G62>
            <G6202></G6202>
            <G6204>040000</G6204>
        </G62>
        <LAD/>
        <N1_Loop>
            <N1>
                <N101>ST</N101>
                <N102></N102>
            </N1>
            <N3>
                <N301>450 Rd</N301>
            </N3>
            <N4>
                <N401></N401>
                <N402>MA</N402>
                <N403></N403>
                <N404>US</N404>
            </N4>
        </N1_Loop>
    </S5_Loop>
    <L3>
        <L301>KGM</L301>
        <L302>G</L302>
    </L3>
    <SE>
        <SE01>1</SE01>
        <SE02></SE02>
    </SE>
</ST_Loop>
```

Output

```
<ST_Loop>
    <N1_Loop>
        <N1>
            <N101>CN</N101>
            <N102></N102>
        </N1>
        <N3>
            <N301>450 Rd</N301>
        </N3>
        <N4>
            <N401></N401>
            <N403>-1300</N403>
            <N404>US</N404>
        </N4>
        <G61>
            <G6101>CN</G6101>
            <G6102> </G6102>
            <G6103>TE</G6103>
            <G6104></G6104>
        </G61>
    </N1_Loop>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <L3>
        <L301>KGM</L301>
        <L302>G</L302>
    </L3>
    <SE>
        <SE01>1</SE01>
        <SE02></SE02>
    </SE>
<S5_Loop>
        <S5>
            <S501>1</S501>
            <S502>LD</S502>
        </S5>
        <G62>
            <G6202>200929</G6202>
            <G6204>010000</G6204>
        </G62>
        <N1_Loop>
            <N1>
                <N101></N101>
            </N1>
            <N3>
                <N301></N301>
            </N3>
            <N4>
                <N401></N401>
                <N403>-1656</N403>
                <N404>US</N404>
            </N4>
        </N1_Loop>
        <OID_Loop/>
    </S5_Loop>
   <S5_Loop>
        <S5>
            <S501>2</S501>
            <S502>UL</S502>
        </S5>
        <G62>
            <G6202></G6202>
            <G6204>040000</G6204>
        </G62>
        <LAD/>
        <N1_Loop>
            <N1>
                <N101>ST</N101>
                <N102></N102>
            </N1>
            <N3>
                <N301>297 Rd</N301>
            </N3>
            <N4>
                <N401></N401>
                <N402>MA</N402>
                <N403>-2802</N403>
                <N404>US</N404>
            </N4>
        </N1_Loop>
    </S5_Loop>
   <S5_Loop>
        <S5>
            <S501>3</S501>
            <S502>LD</S502>
        </S5>
        <G62/>
        <N1_Loop>
            <N1>
                <N101></N101>
            </N1>
            <N3>
                <N301>Rd</N301>
            </N3>
            <N4>
                <N401></N401>
                <N403>-2802</N403>
                <N404>US</N404>
            </N4>
        </N1_Loop>
        <OID_Loop/>
    </S5_Loop>
   <S5_Loop>
        <S5>
            <S501>4</S501>
            <S502>UL</S502>
        </S5>
        <G62>
            <G6202>20210929</G6202>
            <G6204>040000</G6204>
        </G62>
        <LAD/>
        <N1_Loop>
            <N1>
                <N101>ST</N101>
                <N102></N102>
            </N1>
            <N3>
                <N301>St</N301>
            </N3>
            <N4>
                <N401></N401>
                <N402>MA</N402>
                <N403>-3308</N403>
                <N404>US</N404>
            </N4>
        </N1_Loop>
    </S5_Loop>
   <S5_Loop>
        <S5>
            <S501>5</S501>
            <S502>LD</S502>
        </S5>
        <G62/>
        <N1_Loop>
            <N1>
                <N101></N101>
            </N1>
            <N3>
                <N301>t</N301>
            </N3>
            <N4>
                <N401>Rssex</N401>
                <N403>-3308</N403>
                <N404>US</N404>
            </N4>
        </N1_Loop>
        <OID_Loop/>
    </S5_Loop>
   <S5_Loop>
        <S5>
            <S501>6</S501>
            <S502>UL</S502>
        </S5>
        <G62>
            <G6202></G6202>
            <G6204>040000</G6204>
        </G62>
        <LAD/>
        <N1_Loop>
            <N1>
                <N101>ST</N101>
                <N102></N102>
            </N1>
            <N3>
                <N301> Rd</N301>
            </N3>
            <N4>
                <N401></N401>
                <N402>MA</N402>
                <N403>-1300</N403>
                <N404>US</N404>
            </N4>
        </N1_Loop>
    </S5_Loop>
</ST_Loop>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your stylesheet does not specify the specific parent to sort by underlying children. By specifying `<xsl:apply-templates/>` without a `select` path, you instruct processor to copy all children of current node and descendants. However, the sort nodes, `S5/S501`, only exists under `<S5_Loop>`. As a result, the other nodes without xpath returns empty and so sorts first by default ascending order. Try adding `order="descending"` and see `<L3>` and `<SE>` will be at the bottom!

To retain your original style, consider redesigning the `<ST_Loop>` template by re-applying the other nodes in their original placement using `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` and run sorting only on the `S5_Loop` nodes. Also, consider `<xsl:strip-space>` to remove redundant whitespace between nodes and `normalize-space(.)` on all text nodes to remove redundant whitespace inside text values.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   
  <xsl:template match="ST_Loop">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="S5_Loop/preceding-sibling::*[name()!='S5_Loop']"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="S5_Loop">
              <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="S5/S501"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="S5_Loop/following-sibling::*[name()!='S5_Loop']"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This looks working with predetermined nodes like N1_Loop and L3|SE, in case of data nodes that are dynamic and optional nodes above and below S5_Loop, how can we do it.

Comment: See edit using `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` axes.

Comment: That's perfect solution, it worked. Thanks very much.